# Can threading.Event be used to protect variable access in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, events

I have a relatively simple scenario in some Python code where I have two threads, one of which sets a value and the other is waiting for it to be set. My instinct was to reach for `threading.Condition` to implement this but I got wondering whether I could simply use `threading.Event` instead.

So, I have something like this:

```
value = None
readyToRead = threading.Event()

def set():
    # executes in thread 1
    global value
    value = computeValue()
    readyToRead.set()

def get():
    # executes in thread 2
    readyToRead.wait()
    useValue(value)
```

I suppose I am uneasy because access to `value` is not actually mutex protected and I think in some languages at least it might not be safe simply to rely on the ordering implied by the statements in the code.

Is this a valid use of `Event` in Python?

Answer (score 0):

yes this is the valid use-case of event..
value is thread protected.
if you increase the number of thread you have to wait in all thread .if that is the case you can use semaphore to.